# How to remove additional string from Azure Blob Storage uploaded images

Tags: wordpress, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

We moved the media library of a WP site to Azure Blob Storage using the plugin [Microsoft Azure Storage for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/windows-azure-storage/), and added a config to follow the site's upload path, like:

```
https://example.com/app/uploads/2022/12/some-image.jpg
```

This was achieved by setting a container named "app" and making a folder inside it called "uploads" then moving all the media assets there. We also had to add a config to set the `MICROSOFT_AZURE_CONTAINER` into `app/uploads`.

Everything works fine, but when we upload a new image, it has additional string on the media file.

So if I upload a file named `image-placeholder.png`, and when it gets uploaded to Azure Storage, it turns into:

```
https://example.com/app/uploads/2022/12/6391b4e64b763-6391b4e64b764placeholder-image.png.png
```

It adds a random string at the beginning, and re-adds the file extension name.

Does anyone has any idea how this happens, and how I can prevent it?

[image: Screenshot of image uploaded on Azure with additional string & file extension]

Answer (score 0):

*We can remove additional string for the file name, by following the naming conventions while uploading the files. (below is the C# code)*

*Create a Storage account in Azure.*

[image]

*And create a container in storage account*

[image]

*Uploaded files in the container*

[image]

*Uploading files/ images using the below `C#` code*

```
           string mystrconnectionString = "Connection String";
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAcct = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(mystrconnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blob = cloudStorageAcct.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blob.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            CloudBlockBlob myBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);            myBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);
            using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);            myBlockBlob.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);
            uploadFileStream.Close();
```

Comment: I'm sure this is helpful for other people, but the site is on Wordpress and I am using the default Media Library upload for it. It seems to me like upon upload on Azure is when the file name manipulation happens, am I correct?

Comment: Refer to this [link](https://arlanblogs.alvarnet.com/use-azure-blob-storage-to-store-and-deliver-wordpress-images/)